# Rails 4 - CarrierWave default_url not working with asset image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [main, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  version :main do
    process :auto_orient
    process :resize_to_fit => [300, 360]
  end

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.auto_orient
    end
  end
end
```

I have my default image uploaded to app/assets/images/fallback/main/default.png

This default_url is following the standard asset pipeline described by the carrier wave gem.  It doesn't give me an error, but shows no default image only a broken image icon on the view.  However, if there is a valid upload, it shows the upload properly so I know the :thumb, and the :main processes are working.  The only part that is breaking is the default_url, and I have no idea why.  I'm using rails 4 btw.  Any thoughts / ideas?

Thanks!

My code in the view that shows the image if it is uploaded and the broken default url is

```
<div class="img-container">
  <%= image_tag @user.image_url(:main).to_s %>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the size of the png matter?  If so it's 300x400

Answer (score 6):

I just had a similar issue.  Try simply returning "default.png" with nothing else in your default_url method.  From what I can tell, Rails or Carrierwave handles all of the asset pipeline issues itself and will load the default.png correctly with just the name.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using 'main' variable inside `default_url` method, but should `version_name`. If you want use directly 'main' version, you should write next `asset_path("fallback/" + ["main", "default.png"].compact.join('_'))` or just write `"fallback/main_default.png"`.

Also you have wrong pathes:

1. default image uploaded to app/assets/images/fallback/main/default.png
2. default_url will generate next path - 'fallback/main_default.png'